# Segmentation fault when doing recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I get this error when trying to make a recursive function to find the power of something - "bash: line 1:  7269 Segmentation fault: 11 " It works with positive exponents but when I input a negative one, I get that error. 
Here is my code for the function:

```
double intPower( double base, int exponent)
{
    if(exponent>1){
        return base * intPower(base,exponent-1);
    }else if (exponent<0){
        return 1/intPower(base,exponent+1);
    }else{
        return base;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean `-1` in the second case?

Comment: I think I get it. That would make the exponent keep going down but I need to make it go up.

Comment: Ideally you should divide exponent by 2, rather than subtracting every time. That will have better complexity.

Comment: Hmm, now I am getting an error for the actual value of the function. I get .1 for intPower(10,-3).

Comment: Yep. Think about how your logic is working. If the exponent is negative, are you ever multiplying by base to compute the reciprocal correctly? How many times are you computing the reciprocal? (hint: it's more than once, and that's wrong too). And what is the result of intPower(10,0)? Does it return the right answer?

Comment: Oh, I know what I am supposed to do. It shouldn't be exponent -1 or +1. It should be -exponent in the second case.

Comment: You don't handle the case of exponent = 0 correctly.

Comment: It should be return 1 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the case of negative exponent, what you want is

```
1/intPower(base, -exponent);
```

Otherwise your exponent will still be negative and subtracting one from it just makes it go further away from 0 also you end up with alot of 1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/....

Answer (score 0):

This will infinitely recurse since subtracting one will never get closer to 0

```
return 1/intPower(base,exponent-1);
```

Perhaps you meant this:

```
return 1/intPower(base,exponent+1);
```

**EDIT**

looking at it a little more, you probably also need to multiply that value by the base

```
return 1 / (base * intPower(base,exponent+1));
```

Putting it all together (and adding in 1 more case you are missing, since you need to handle exponent of 1 and exponent of 0 differently):

```
double intPower( double base, int exponent)
{
    if(exponent>1){
        return base * intPower(base,exponent-1);
    }else if (exponent<0){
        return 1 / (base * intPower(base,exponent+1));
    }else if (exponent==1){
        return base;
    }else if (exponent==0){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this wont work because 1/intPower(base, exponent + 1) will still go into the exponent < 0 case and then you end up with a long nested 1/1/1/1/1/1/1/base

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun good point, was just solving the seg fault problem, didn't realize the algorithm was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here, it think.

```
}else if (exponent<0){
    return 1/intPower(base,exponent-1);
}
```

The -1 should be a +1, otherwise you'll just keep subtracting forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if exponent is equal to 0 you should return 1.:)

The problem is in this statement

```
return 1/intPower(base,exponent-1);
```

Try to change it to

```
return 1/intPower(base,exponent + 1);
```

Comment: this wont work because 1/intPower(base, exponent + 1) will still go into the exponent < 0 case and then you end up with a long nested 1/1/1/1/1/1/1/base